# Animate icon and affect other icons - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I found this JSFiddle that fit my needs and is exactly what I am looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/usNdK/

but I want to add some more effects to it. When I hover over one icon, I want the other 3 icons to animate the opposite direction as well, is that possible?

Also, I plan to replace these icons with .svg files and I am able to apply opacity on them but I can't apply color to them when I hover over it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#divSocial a img").css({ opacity: 0.5 });
     $("#divSocial a img").hover(
            function () {
                            $(this).animate({ top: "-15" });
                            $(this).css({ opacity: 1 });
            }, 
            function () {
                            $(this).animate({ top: "0" });
                        $(this).css({ opacity: 0.5 });
            }
        );
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/usNdK/626/ Here is the animate in the opposite direction!

Comment: Thank you @Pedro Estrada, This solutions worked best without the unexpected behaviour of the other solutions, why don't you post below and I will upvote it!

Comment: Thank you @TJXStyles!! I'll be sure to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/usNdK/626/)

This is how you would animate the other ones to go **downwards**

I added `.stop()` to the `.animate({..})` so that the image doesnt keep jumping if you pass over it multiple times really fast.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#divSocial a img").css({
        opacity: 0.5
    });
    $("#divSocial a img").hover(

    function () {
        $("#divSocial a img").not(this).stop().animate({
            top: "15"
        });
        $(this).stop().animate({
            top: "-15"
        });
        $(this).css({
            opacity: 1
        });
    },

    function () {
        $("#divSocial a img").not(this).stop().animate({
            top: "0"
        });
        $(this).stop().animate({
            top: "0"
        });
        $(this).css({
            opacity: 0.5
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure!

I used your jsFiddle as an example. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#divSocial a img").css({ opacity: 0.5 });
         $("#divSocial a img").hover(
            function () {
                $(this).animate({ top: "-15" });
                $(this).css({ opacity: 1 });
                $("#divSocial a img").not($(this)).animate({ top: "15" });
        }, 
        function () {
            $(this).animate({ top: "0" });
            $(this).css({ opacity: 0.5 });
            $("#divSocial a img").not($(this)).animate({ top: "0" });
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class on your images for that purpose, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#divSocial a img").css({ opacity: 0.5 });
        $("#divSocial a img").addClass("go-down");
        $("#divSocial a img").hover(
                function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("go-down");
                    $(this).animate({ top: "-15" });
                    $(this).css({ opacity: 1 });
                    $("#divSocial a img.go-down").animate({ top: "15" });
                }, 
                function () {
                    $(this).addClass("go-down");
                    $(this).animate({ top: "0" });
                    $(this).css({ opacity: 0.5 });
                }
            );
    });
```